# Do different phones have different accelerometer quality? Is there a way to measure it?

Tags: sensors

I'm creating an Android application that basically detects the vibration of a car on streets and saves the data in a file that I'll analyze later. But I'm curious to know if there's such a thing as an "accelerometer accuracy" on different phones.

If there is, is it possible to measure the accelerometer quality of a specific phone? What are the parameters I should be paying attention when I want a phone with a very good accelerometer sensitivity and accuracy?

Comment: I've gotten some specific sensor information on my phone's sensors from an app like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anu.developers3k.mydevice.  It queries the phone and gets sensor information as well as the sensor data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quality of the sensor is mainly determined by the used sensor chip.

For a lot of devices you can find the info which sensor chip is used for providing the accelerometer/gyroscope sensor data. E.g. you can find it in a tear-down article of the device.

With that info you can review the technical data-sheet of the used chip(s) and compare them or ask the electronic tinker scene on the net for their thoughts or recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know what sensor is inside your phone, you should download Cpu-Z. It provides information about all hardware inside your phone and gives the name of the chips. So you can google for more information.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z